# Java generics - Why is this assignment in the constructor illegal?

Tags: java, generics

Why do I get a compiler error in this code ? How do I fix it ?

```
public class Container<T> {
    private T content;
    private T defaultValue;

    public <T> Container(T defaultValue){
        //Compiler error - incompatible types: T cannot be converted to T.
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }
}
```

After type erasure, `T defaultValue` would become `Object defaultValue`. Then why can't we assign `T defaultValue` to `Object defaultValue` ? After all, every type in Java is an Object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the `<T>` from in front of the constructor. Java thinks you are trying to create a new generic. It thinks the T you have in the class statement is a different T then you have in the constructor. In Java's eyes you have T1 and T2. You are trying to assign T2 to a T1 variables. Even though they may be identical in methods, inheritance, etc... they are two distinct generics.

This is how Java interprets what you've written.

```java
public class Container<T1> {
    private T1 content;
    private T1 defaultValue;

    public <T2> Container(T2 defaultValue){
        //Compiler error - incompatible types: T cannot be converted to T.
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }
}
```

What you meant to write was this. You don't need to specify T inside < > anywhere since it's included in the class syntax.

```java
public class Container<T> {
    private T content;
    private T defaultValue;

    public Container(T defaultValue){
        this.defaultValue = defaultValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason that the compiler error is produced is because of the `<T>` in the constructor.
The presence of `<T>` means that the method is expecting a new generic parameter T. A generic parameter that is different from the one the class expects. Remove the `<T>` in the method signature and your program will compile.

Answer (score 0):

public  Container(T defaultValue){ means that it returns value but constructors can not return any value explicitly.
you can write:

```
Container(T content, T defaultValue) {
```

this is full example.

```
public class Test {
public static void main(String [] args) {
Container<String> container = new Container<>("value1","value2");        



}
}
class Container <T> {
    private T content;
    private T defaultValue;
Container(T content, T defaultValue) {
this.content=content;
this.defaultValue =defaultValue;
}
}
```